# File .htc files - Do I need web server?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, internet-explorer

I want to use [PIE](http://css3pie.com/) in my project with IE7.

However something I didn't understand is can i you use .htc files only on web server?

Can i use it in local pages loaded via browser without webserver?

I seen at PIE's documentation and they said this text below:

> Serving the correct Content-Type
>
> IE requires that HTC behaviors are served up with a content-type
>   header of "text/x-component", otherwise it will simply ignore the
>   behavior. Many web servers are preconfigured to serve the correct
>   content-type, but others are not.
>
> If you have problems with the PIE behavior not being applied, check
>   your server configuration and if possible update it to use the correct
>   content-type. For Apache, you can do this in a .htaccess file:
>
> AddType text/x-component .htc

So if i need load via "text/x-component" Can i do that via AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with AJAX :)

It's just a response header of the file. E.G. A HTML page is usually text/html "content-type". A javascript file is application/javascript. This is called the mime type or content type, and helps the browser know what type of file its receiving.

You need to either add a .htaccess file into your web project in the main folder, that has:

`AddType text/x-component                    htc`

or add that exact same line into your apache/virtual host configuration.

Comment: So Doesn't exists ways to do this without webserver? Because in my project run local machine and it didn't use webserver only pages .html

Comment: So are you just loading the file in your browser as `file://C:\something\something.html`? If so, then I do not believe it is possible, and will just revert to your browsers default. Or are you loading it at like `http://localhost`?

Comment: I can use this for apply CSS 3 in IE 7 without webserver